# Angular Material table with Firebase data - paginator and sort show but do not work

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material, angular5

I have a Angular Material table with data from a Firebase database that populates as expected, however when I try to follow the docs to add paginator and sort they are both visible (I can see the paginator div and options and the animated sorting on clicking header) but neither work i.e sort or change items viewed.

How can I investigate this?

Html snippet:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    ...

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>

<mat-paginator 
    #paginator
    [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

TS:

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

...

itemList: Item[];
displayedColumns = ['name', 'quantity', 'description', 'equippable', 'attunement', 'edit', 'delete'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.itemList);

...

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

...


ngOnInit() {

    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    let data = this.itemService.getData();
    data.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
        this.itemList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
            let json = element.payload.toJSON();
            json["$key"] = element.key;
            this.itemList.push(json as Item);
        });
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.itemList);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out that because I'm storing the Firebase data in a subscription if I initiate the sorting and pagination like the demo it will not work. I have to initiate the sorting and pagination after the subscription is set in the ngOnInit like so:

```
ngOnInit() {

    let data = this.itemService.getData();
    data.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {

        this.itemList = [];

        item.forEach(element => {
            let json = element.payload.toJSON();
            json["$key"] = element.key;
            this.itemList.push(json as Item);
        });

        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.itemList);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an function to get data once, define the function as follows : This function get the data from Firestore.

```
    async getAnimalData() {
        await this.animalRef.get().then(QuerySnapshot => {
          QuerySnapshot.forEach(QueryDocumentSnapshot => {
            console.log(QueryDocumentSnapshot.data().Gender_Type)
              this.herd.push(QueryDocumentSnapshot.data());
          })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Then in your ngOnInit() function, use :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAnimalData().then(val =>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.herd);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      });
    });
}
```

The async function will return a promise and .then will be evaluated after completing the async function.
Hope it helps!